# tikzlibrary: circuits.ee.IEC: ohm symbol

Tags: fonts, symbols, luatex, tikz-circuit-lib, fontsetup

With this latex code I get the correct picture.

```
\documentclass[12pt,table]{standalone}

%\usepackage[lucida]{fontsetup}
%\usepackage[default]{fontsetup}
%\usepackage[times]{fontsetup}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary {circuits.ee.IEC}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[circuit ee IEC]
\draw (0,0) to [resistor={ohm=4}] (0,1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

But when I comment in one of the `fontsetup` lines and use `lualatex` the ohm/omega symbol is missing: Missing character: There is no ùõ∫ (U+1D6FA) in font ...
I read already about the missing ohm symbol but I found no solution to that problem in connection with `circuits.ee.IEC` `tikzlibrary` where I don't use `siunitx`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tikz` option `resistor={ohm=4}` will add a node with text `$\mathrm{4\Omega}$`. Hence the example can be further simplified to the one below, without `tikz`.

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[default]{fontsetup}

\tracinglostchars=3 % just to raise error(s) for missing char(s)

\begin{document}
$\mathrm{\Omega}$
\end{document}
```

Compile it and you get an error

```tex
! Missing character: There is no  (U+1D6FA) in font [NewCM10-Book.otf]/OT:script=latn;language=dflt;.
l.9 $\mathrm{\Omega}$
```

Since `fontsetup` loads both `fontspec` and `unicode-math`, I would suggest to config `unicode-math` by adding

```tex
\PassOptionsToPackage{mathrm=sym}{unicode-math}
```

before loading `fontsetup`. See package manual for `unicode-math`, sec. 4.4.2 "Replacing ‘text math’ fonts by symbols" for more info.

Applied to OP's example

```tex
\PassOptionsToPackage{mathrm=sym}{unicode-math}
\documentclass[12pt,table, margin=5pt]{standalone} % add some page margin

%\usepackage[lucida]{fontsetup}
\usepackage[default]{fontsetup}
%\usepackage[times]{fontsetup}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary {circuits.ee.IEC}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[circuit ee IEC]
\draw (0,0) to [resistor={ohm=4}] (0,1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It seems that learning never end. Thank you.